# Slick3 with SQLite - autocommit seems to not be working

Tags: scala, sqlite, slick

I'm trying to write some basic queries with Slick for SQLite database

Here is my code:

```
class MigrationLog(name: String) {

    val migrationEvents = TableQuery[MigrationEventTable]

    lazy val db: Future[SQLiteDriver.backend.DatabaseDef] = {
        val db = Database.forURL(s"jdbc:sqlite:$name.db", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")
        val setup = DBIO.seq(migrationEvents.schema.create)

        val createFuture = for {
          tables <- db.run(MTable.getTables)
          createResult <- if (tables.length  == 0) db.run(setup) else Future.successful()
        } yield createResult

        createFuture.map(_ => db)
    }

    val addEvent: (String, String) => Future[String] = (aggregateId, eventType) => {
        val id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString
        val command = DBIO.seq(migrationEvents += (id, aggregateId, None, eventType, "CREATED", System.currentTimeMillis, None))
        db.flatMap(_.run(command).map(_ => id))
    }

    val eventSubmitted: (String, String) => Future[Unit] = (id, batchId) => {
       val q = for { e <- migrationEvents if e.id === id } yield (e.batchId, e.status, e.updatedAt)
       val updateAction = q.update(Some(batchId), "SUBMITTED", Some(System.currentTimeMillis))
       db.map(_.run(updateAction))
    }

    val eventMigrationCompleted: (String, String, String) => Future[Unit] = (batchId, id, status) => {
       val q = for { e <- migrationEvents if e.batchId === batchId && e.id === id} yield (e.status, e.updatedAt)
       val updateAction = q.update(status, Some(System.currentTimeMillis))
       db.map(_.run(updateAction))
    }

    val allEvents = () => {
        db.flatMap(_.run(migrationEvents.result))
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm using it:

```
val migrationLog = MigrationLog("test")
val events = for {
  id <- migrationLog.addEvent("aggregateUserId", "userAccessControl")
  _ <- migrationLog.eventSubmitted(id, "batchID_generated_from_idam")
  _ <- migrationLog.eventMigrationCompleted("batchID_generated_from_idam", id, "Successful")
  events <- migrationLog.allEvents()
} yield events

events.map(_.foreach(event => event match {
  case (id, aggregateId, batchId, eventType, status, submitted, updatedAt) => println(s"$id $aggregateId $batchId $eventType $status $submitted $updatedAt")
}))
```

The idea is to add event first, then update it with batchId (which also updates status) and then update the status when the job is done. `events` should contain events with status `Successful`.

What happens is that after running this code it prints events with status `SUBMITTED`. If I wait a while and do the same `allEvents` query or just go and check the db from command line using `sqlite3` then it's updated correctly.
I'm properly waiting for futures to be resolved before starting the next operation, auto-commit should be enabled by default.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with `db.map(_.run(updateAction))` which returns `Future[Future[Int]]` which means that the command was not finished by the time I tried to run another query.

Replacing it with `db.flatMap(_.run(updateAction))` solved the issue.